# Trigger Google Maps from Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a website designed for the android browser using jquery/jqtouch.  As a part of it, i have a map page that loads.  In the process of displaying my data, I found that some of my customer's addresses, when clicked kick of the google app map, with the data sent to it.  It also seems to load and run a ton faster (as well as having all the benefits of navigation, etc).

So I've searched and searched, but am unable to "emulate" that built in function of kicking off the address.  I've tried links with geo: and maps:, etc, but to none will open the installed app.  Yet, just having a `<li></li>` item with an address, the browser will detect a "proper" address and open the app.

I don't care if i have to kick it off with javascript, or a href, it just has to be embedded in the html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see (at http://m.google.com/maps?dc=gbackstop ) there is a link: if you have Google Map app - 'Launch it now' and it links to following:

```
geo:28.61170,77.2747?z=15
```

I have verified above in address bar (goes to Delhi CWG games) and it works on my HTC Desire web browser.

From the android [intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), A zoom level of 1 shows the whole Earth, abd highest being 23:

```
geo:latitude,longitude
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the geo:0,0?q=... but that didn't launch.  I'll see if using the real coordinates works....  Thanks.

Comment: Update 2.  I'm marking yours as the answer.  It appears that jqtouch must be messing with the call, because when i put it on a static page on the droid, it popped both my address, and the geo code into the map program.

Comment: Update 3:  Got it working.  Thanks! had to add a reference in jqtouch.js to recognize that geo: was an external link.